# combine lists in R without knowing beforehand the number of lists to combine

Tags: r, list

If I was starting with a list A that contained lists N and M, which contain equal number of elements:

```
A = list( N=list( a=c(1,1), b=c(2,2)),
          M=list( a=c(1,1), b=c(2,2)) )
```

I would do the following to combine each of the elements from the lists N and M into new lists

```
B = mapply( FUN=list, A[[1]], A[[2]], SIMPLIFY=FALSE )
```

to get

```
>B
$a
$a[[1]]
[1] 1 1

$a[[2]]
[1] 1 1


$b
$b[[1]]
[1] 2 2

$b[[2]]
[1] 2 2
```

How can I do the same thing as above if I don't know beforehand the number of lists that the list A will have?

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better solution to your problem, but if you literally want to "do the same thing, but without knowing size of `A`", you can do the following:

```
do.call(function(...) mapply(..., FUN = list, SIMPLIFY = FALSE), A)
```

Comment: @flodel, that might be worth posting as an answer

Answer (score 1):

try using `tapply`:

```
 tapply(U, inds, list)
```

Where

```
 U    <- unlist(A, recursive=FALSE)
 inds <- rep(seq_along(A[[1]]), length(A))
```